# How to parse Json response in android from retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Hi Guys can anyone help me to parse the following json response.

```
{
"result": "success",
"reason": "Operation completed successfully.",
"api": "authenticate_inmate",
"locked": false,
"payload": {
    "authenticated": true,
    "inmate_details": {
        "jail_alt_id": "9584",
        "facility_number": "1047",
        "last_name": "ARMSTRONG",
        "first_name": "DONALD",
        "dob": "19601213",
        "middle_name": "LEROY",
        "sex": "M",
        "account_frozen": "N",
        "balance": "122.73",
        "pin": "9584",
        "location": "HU H 121B",
        "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000369",
        "indigent": 0
    },
    "order_id": "5d1f7c10-833f-0139-4675-3c97e15872c0",
    "order_detail": [{
        "id": null,
        "order_id": "5d1f7c10-833f-0139-4675-3c97e15872c0",
        "product_code": "5010",
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "transaction_history": "\"1/25/21\",\"1.12\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"1/25/21\",\"2.11\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"1/25/21\",\"1.41\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"1/25/21\",\"0.34\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"1/25/21\",\"1.41\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"1/22/21\",\"16.00\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"12/22/20\",\"10.00\",\"Depositor: Testing LastName\"\r\n\"12/21/20\",\"10.00\",\"Deposit Holding Account (100199)\"\r\n\"11/20/20\",\"-1.00\",\"Commissary (100301)\"\r\n\"11/06/20\",\"5.00\",\"Deposit Holding Account (100199)\"\r\n"
}
```

}

I want to get inmate_details, Order id, order details & transaction history. i need to show those details in individual screen. i generated model class from json online & i tried in retrofit, but i am getting the response as null. i added my code below, thanks

```
apIservice=ApiClient.getClient().create(APIService.class);                    
                call=apIservice.checkLogin(inmate_id,pin);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Payload>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Payload> call, Response<Payload> response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                          Inmate_details balance = response.body().getInmate_details();
                            pDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            Toasty.success(LoginActivity.this, "Success! Redirecting To Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,PDFActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is Payload?  Are you using some library like GSON or Jackson to convert from JSON to a Java object?  Because that functionality isn't a native part of retrofit, you need to either do it by hand or use a library like those.

Comment: it is model class i am using, but all fields are showing as null, i added the console output in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse `json` like below:

```
// ResponseObject is your root object
public class ResponseObject{
    
    @SerializedName("payload")
    private Payload payload;

   public Payload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
class Payload{
    @SerializedName("authenticated")
    private boolean isAuthenticated;

    @SerializedName("inmate_details")
    private InMateObject inMateObject;

    @SerializedName("order_id")
    private String orderId;

    @SerializedName("order_detail")
    private List<Order> orderList;

 // Make sure to get String value as response for "transaction_history" key
    @SerializedName("transaction_history")
    private String transactionDetails;

    public InMateObject getInMateObject() {
        return inMateObject;
    }
}
class InMateObject{
    @SerializedName("jail_alt_id")
    private String jainAltId;
    @SerializedName("facility_number")
    private String facilityNumber;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("dob")
    private String dob;
    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    @SerializedName("sex")
    private String sex;
    // Add other fields like wise.

}
class Order{
    @SerializedName("id")  // If id is Integer in json then use int type
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("order_id")
    private String orderId;
    @SerializedName("product_code")
    private String productCode;
    @SerializedName("quantity")
    private int quantity;
}
```

And then your `Api` call would look like below:

```
         call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseObject> call, Response<ResponseObject> response) {
        System.out.println(response);
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            //Inmate_details balance = response.body().getInmate_details();
            // Basically you are getting ResponseObject as response. So, collect payload first from it. And then collect inmate_details from Payload.
            Payload payload = response.body().getPayload();
            InMateObject inMateObject = payload.getInMateObject();
            pDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
            Toasty.success(LoginActivity.this, "Success! Redirecting To Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,PDFActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for help. now all the data's are coming. thanks a lot

Comment: how i can get that transaction details? it look like a json string format i think. can you guiide me to get that too

Comment: I can see you are getting String as value for transaction_history. So you can check it out , I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi i have string value of transaction details like with more special characters. i cant able to parse it. i need to display those details in recyclerview like date, amount & description. how can i do this? because there is no keys in that string.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private fun getRetrofitObject() : Retrofit {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("Api Link")
                .build()
        return retrofit
    }

    //Calling API Add User
    private fun callAddUserAPI() {
        val apiInterface = getRetrofitObject().create(APIInterface::class.java)
        val userRequest = AddUserRequest(editTextName.text.toString(), editTextEmail.text.toString())
        val addUserAPI = apiInterface.addUserAPI(userRequest)
        addUserAPI.enqueue(object : Callback<AddUserResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AddUserResponse>, request: Response<AddUserResponse>) {
                val body = request.body()
               Log.i(DATA, body?.name.toString())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AddUserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i(DATA, FAILURE_MESSAGE)
            }
        })
    }
```

Try this, maybe this will hepful.